# Python Tkinter: Remove window border

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, border

How do you remove the border of a TopLevel without using overrideredirect?

```
TopLevel.overrideredirect(True)
```

It would be great if a sample code can be provided.

Python 2.7.3, Linux, Tkinter version $Revision: 81008 $

Comment: What problem do you have with overrideredirect? The reason it exists is exactly what you're asking for -- to remove the window manager border.

Comment: Well I made a progress bar and by using overrideredirect it hides the border. However, it does not work when I do TopLevel.transient(parentWindow). The reason I use transient is because I want to minimize the progress bar once its parent is minimized too. But if overrideredirect is set to True, using TopLevel.transient(parentWindow) does not do anything

Comment: Can you use Linux equivalent to Windows WinAPI?

Comment: I can only run my code on Linux, if that's what you mean :)

Comment: I mean that I do not know how to do it directly in Tk, but I am able to do it using window handle and WinAPI calls by 4 lines of code without any side effects. There should be something similar in Linux.

Comment: Hopefully. Right now I'm still clueless and my program does not look good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Bryan Oakley, I have realized a solution that would allow me to use 'overrideredirect' while solving my problem, and that is using 'Unmap' event.

The following example code shows that when the additional window can be minimized with the main window when using 'Map' and 'Unmap':

```
import Tkinter
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        Tkinter.Label(self.root, text="main window").pack()
        self.window = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.window.overrideredirect(True)
        Tkinter.Label(self.window, text="Additional window").pack()
        self.root.bind("<Unmap>", self.OnUnMap)
        self.root.bind("<Map>", self.OnMap)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def OnMap(self, e):
        self.window.wm_deiconify()
    def OnUnMap(self, e):
        self.window.wm_withdraw()
app=App()
```