# How does one remove all window borders from a process in Python?

Tags: python, window

How can one remove all window borders from a process (not just a specific window) in Python? Having tried searching, what was found was "removing window borders from a tkinter-created window", which was not desirable.
Looking forward to a package that can do that.

Comment: Could we get a broader context? What framework do you use? By border, do you mean the terminal-based border? The window border you are generating? If so, which framework are you using, please?

Comment: @SimonProvost I suspect he's saying he hasn't found a way in tkinter, and is looking for an alternate framework that can do it.  Unfortunately that would make it off-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter: Remove window border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111299/python-tkinter-remove-window-border)

Comment: Use this  borderwidth=0